# Blocking the scrollbar on a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, scrollbar

Is it possible to block the use of the scroll bar in a Matlab GUI interface?

The bar appears when I display a table on my GUI, but as it contains too much data, the scrolling using the scroll bar sometimes lags and makes it so that the user has to wait until the results are displayed before doing anything else on the interface.

I would like to make it so that only the arrows could be used to scroll, and not the scroll bar as you can not scroll down too fast with the arrows, making so that the interface would not freeze.

I am forced to display theses huge tables of data on the interface, and I haven't found a way to make the display of the data faster while scrolling.

Comment: Are you talking about the scrollbar which appear in a `uitable` control when the content is larger than the viewport, or just a conventional `slider` uicontrol ? Also precise your version of Matlab, as the `uitable` control has seen many changes recently.

Comment: you can set the table's `Enable` property to `off`, and after everything is put on the table, you can put it `on` again.

Comment: @Hoki : I indeed talk about the scrollbar from a `uitable`. My current Matlab version is 2013b. @scmg : If i disable the uitable, i won't be able to move in the table at all. Plus, i don't think that it will load data that are not on the display window, it only load data when you scroll, so i don't think this is a solution to my issue.

Comment: you're going to have to poke deep into the java component behind the Matlab `uitable` to be able to retrieve a handle for the scrollbar and control it (if even possible). If you do not feel so comfortable with java/undocumented Matlab, another option is to only load in your table a subset which can be displayed on screen, and program a couple of buttons to navigate the records (each button press you reload a new small table with just a few columns or rows changed).